# What is the definition of a "memory subsystem"?

Tags: memory, terminology

I am reading some articles discussing about "memory subsystems". What is the definition for memory subsystems?

As far as I understand by googling or reading other documents, it kind of indicates a group of main memory and processor cache. Is that correct?

Comment: General computing questions are not on-topic on Stack Overflow -- nor were they in 2011.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, do you know of a more appropriate Stack Exchange site for general computing questions? Super User, perhaps?

Comment: Reading https://superuser.com/help/on-topic, questions that are about "computer hardware" or "computer software", and not specific to programming (or subject to other exemptions that don't appear to apply) are on-topic there -- so yes, Super User is indeed a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of memory subsystem comoponents, RAM (R) components, single access (S) components, and dual-access (D) components. All memory subsystem components are for automatically retrieving operands from and storing results in their associated memory modules. All memory subsystem components have an output data connection and an input data connection. Therefore, they must be capable of handling both an output data stream and an input data stream. In addition, a D component includes a second pair of input and output connections. All memory subsystem components have a queue in each of their input and output data streams.

A significant difference between the memory subsystem components and the other components is that a Number of Operands In (NumOpsIn) register as well as a NumOpsOut register must be included. The NumOpsIn register serves the same purpose for the input data stream as NumOpsOut does for the output stream. Both NumOpsIn and NumOpsOut must be zero before new instructions can be distributed to the component's programmable registers.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for answering. But I already read this article on another web page...

Comment: Ya.. so whats your confusion ? This is a clear article.I had added the original link but later edited and removed it.As i thought this is enough.

Comment: @bilash.saha, quoting someone else's text verbatim without providing the link is plagarism; editing that link out was inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The term "memory subsystem" seems to refer to a DRAM module, not CPU caches, and not CPU registers. I claim this based on the usages of the term listed below.

However, each usage is in the context of CPU caches, cache misses, and performance.

---

Here's a sample of usages:

---

Ulrich Drepper in *What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory*:

> Unfortunately, neither the structure nor the cost of using **the memory**
> **subsystem** of a computer **or** **the caches on CPUs** is well understood by
> most programmers.

---

Intel in *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual*:

The manual also distinguishes between **cache** and **the memory subsystems**

> Memory Bound corresponds to execution stalls related to the **cache** and
> **memory subsystems**.

---

Intel's VTune Profiler lumps CPU caches in with DRAM when listing things related to "memory subsystem issues", but doesn't claim that CPU caches are part of a "memory subsystem":

> This metric shows how memory subsystem **issues** affect the performance. [...]

[image: an Intel VTune Profiler summary]

---

The manual contrasts between an **on-package** memory subsystem and an **off-package** memory subsystem ("main memory") in Knights Landing:

> MCDRAM is **an on-package**, high bandwidth **memory subsystem** that provides
> peak bandwidth for read traffic, but lower bandwidth for write traffic
> (compared to reads). The aggregate bandwidth provided by MCDRAM is
> higher than **the off-package memory subsystem** (i.e., DDR memory).